# SQL Server ignoring collation from database

Tags: sql-server, docker, flyway

So for tests I am creating temporary docker SQL Server.
Unfortunately my production database uses some non standard collation.

So for tests I am creating test database with my custom collation. In next step using flyway I am migrating schema, but it seems like even database has my custom collation, flyway SQL statements inherit collation from SQL Server instance and I am getting collation collision exception.

Is there any way to force that every statement in database x should use database collation by default?

One important thing is that many of those SQLs are already on production, so I cannot add to them collation statement explicit.

Comment: I'm confused, if you copy an existing database schema you will get the same collation? Collation is set for the entire database and can then be over-written for individual string columns. So long as you maintain the same setting on your test database it should all be OK? 1 thing to keep in mind is that some queries might spill to tempdb, so therefore that needs to be the same collation as your original server. But in direct answer to your question, no, there is no way to force all collations in all queries.

Comment: I am confused also. I ve made especially test database with collation x. None of flyway scripts has overriden collation in statements. But somehow I am getting collation collision exception between test db and sql server instance default...

Comment: Maybe its tempdb, your test server might have a different default collation.

Comment: I dont have idea what is tempdb in this context. Am i ale to change its collation?

Comment: https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/changing-the-collation-of-the-tempdb-database/

Comment: Thanks I will test it